overlapping shadow in kivymd
so I want to make this shape in kivymd.

And I think, why don't I just stack two cards together! But, then I realize, the drop shadow from each card will be overlapping. Is there a way so that the shadow will not overlap? or is that any method other than using card to make this shape?
